# Leer un valor entre dos etiquetas en un string

Tags: c#

Yo estoy recibiendo un xml en forma de string Ejemplo:

```
POST xml.xml HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 280

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<NODO1>
    <PARAM1>VALOR1</PARAM1>
    <PARAM2>VALOR2</PARAM2>
    <PARAM3>VALOR3</PARAM3>
    <PARAM4>VALOR4</PARAM4>
    <PARAM5>VALOR5</PARAM5>
    <PARAM6>VALOR6</PARAM6>
    <PARAM7>VALOR7</PARAM7> 
    <PARAM8>VALOR8</PARAM8>
</NODO1>
```

Yo necesito saber si esta vacio entre la apertura y cierre de NODO1 Ejemplo:

```
POST xml.xml HTTP/1.1Content-Type: application/xmlContent-Length: 280<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><NODO1>Aca</NODO1>
```

Gracias saludos.

Comment: ¿Dentro del Nodo1 puede venir cualquier cosa o tiene que ser <PARAM1>VALOR1</PARAM1><PARAM2>...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es ver el contenido entre las etiquetas  podrías empezar por obtener la posición de < NODO1> y < /NODO1> dentro del texto recibido de la siguiente manera:
Suponiendo que el texto está en la variable 'texto' y ésta es de tipo string

```
var posicionInicial = texto.indexOf("<NODO1>") + 7;
var posicionFinal = texto.indexOf("</NODO1>";
```

Ahora queda validar si la posición inicial y la final son diferentes, si son diferentes es porque existe algún texto entre estas dos etiquetas. Si existe un texto y deseas extraerlo, podrías hacerlo con:

```
var textoNodo1 = texto.Substring(posicionInicial, (posicionFinal - posicionInicial));
```

Comment: gracias lo termine resolviendo asi se me ocurrio despues de publicar. Lo unico que yo no hice substring xq necesitaba saber si estaba vacio no necesitaba tomar lo que estaba entre las etiquetas. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría lo siguiente..
Primero convertí tu string a un **XmlDocument**

```
    string a = "<NODO1>" +
    "<PARAM1> <b>VALOR1</b> </PARAM1>" +
    "<PARAM2> VALOR2 </PARAM2>" +
    "<PARAM3> VALOR3 </PARAM3>" +
    "<PARAM4> VALOR4 </PARAM4>" +
    "<PARAM5> VALOR5 </PARAM5>" +
    "<PARAM6> VALOR6 </PARAM6>" +
    "<PARAM7> VALOR7 </PARAM7>" +
    "<PARAM8> VALOR8 </PARAM8>" +
    "</NODO1>";

    //Converto a Xml Document
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(a);

    //Pregunto por el NODO 1
    if (xml.SelectSingleNode("NODO1") != null){MessageBox.Show("Existe");}
    else{ MessageBox.Show("No Existe!");}

    //Pregunto por PARAM1
    if (xml.SelectSingleNode("//PARAM1") != null){MessageBox.Show("Existe");}
    else{ MessageBox.Show("No Existe!");}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Parece una manera mas segura que manejarla como string. La voy a probar gracias!